# How to have a js Function and form submit at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, function

hoping someone can see where im going wrong. Working on this photo upload page(still!) and cant for the life of me get the page to delete a photo from a file on the server and remove the table row with the photo/file info on it. My issue is that when I delete the photo file and table data the page refreshes but still shows a broken link to the NOW missing file. A second refresh fixes this but that is hardly desirable. To fix this i have written a js Function that removes the actual img element. But as I have said I cant get them both to work at the same time only one or the other. I have tried using the forms "onsubmit" I have tried adding the .submit() function within my js function, I am currently using an HTML button with onclick to call my function but i also have a "submit" button that i was original trying to use with he forms onsubmit as well but nothing seems to work.
Here is what i have so far...

```
$photoQuery= "SELECT * FROM photo_index WHERE listing_ID='$listingID'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $photoQuery);
            $img_count =0;

while ($photo_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $img_ID = "pic" . $img_count;
            $form_ID = "form" . $img_count;
        echo "<form name='$form_ID' id='$form_ID' action=listing_photos.php method=post > ";
        echo "<input type=hidden name=photoDir value='$photo_data[Photo_Dir]' />";
        echo "<input type=submit name=photoDel id=submit_but value=Delete />";
        echo "</form>";             

        echo "<button type=button id=del_button onclick=delPhoto('$img_ID', '$form_ID')>Delete!!</button>";
        echo "<img src='$photo_data[Photo_Dir]' height=100px width=100px id='$img_ID'>";

        $img_count = $img_count +1;
}


            if (isset($_POST['photoDel'])){
                $fh = fopen($_POST['photoDir'], 'a');
                fclose($fh);
                unlink($_POST['photoDir']);

                $photoDel= "DELETE FROM photo_index WHERE Photo_Dir='$_POST[photoDir]'";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $photoDel) or die(mysql_error());

                echo "Photo Removed";

            }
```

And here is my JS function i was using to remove the img element...

```
function delPhoto(photoElem) {


     var a = document.getElementById('photo_container');
     var b = document.getElementById(photoElem);

    a.removeChild(b);
    return true;
```

}

Sorry i know this is a bit messy (there is also SQL injection issues) but like i say i have tried everything in every order I can think of. The delete file and table row works on its own and the js function works on its own so i know there is no issue there just cant get them to both run at the same time. I have been starting to experiment with JQuery but i am very new to that so would prefer to keep this in php, js if possible. IF not im open to any suggestions.

Comment: Note: This page uploads multiple pics and displays them under the upload form with a delete button to remove them if needed.

Comment: you can edit your question, you don't need to post comments explaining additional stuff

Comment: you have to write yot delete code at the top before the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this to the top, you are processing the delete after having selected the image from the database, all you have to do is first delete, then select from the database, this way the image you just deleted won't show again.

```
if (isset($_POST['photoDel'])){
    $fh = fopen($_POST['photoDir'], 'a');
    fclose($fh);
    unlink($_POST['photoDir']);
    $photoDel= "DELETE FROM photo_index WHERE Photo_Dir='$_POST[photoDir]'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $photoDel) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Photo Removed";

}
```

You don't need the the javascript function anymore

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I feel like the biggest idiot ever... wasted almost a full day trying to get this to work!!! Cheers,